# installing app on USB LIVE in UEFI MODE

Tags: usb, uefi

I would like to install boot repair on my live Usb.
When I am logged in Uefi mode, the installation of all software on the key is not persistent. I mean, when I install a software such as boot repair, and I close this session and then I reconnect, I have to reinstall the same software. That's why I say that the installation is not persistent. While when the key is connected in Legacy mode, the installed software still remains.
How to make it possible in Uefi mode.
Thank you.

Comment: The live installer is not updateable. It is an installer that can be run in live mode. You can save some data if you want to create another partition for persistence. It only then saves downloading software again, but still have to reinstall. https://askubuntu.com/questions/850319/multiboot-with-multiple-persistent-partitions Or you can do a full install from one flash drive to a larger flash drive.

Comment: You can create Ubuntu **persistent live** (in a USB pendrive, memory card or SSD (connected via USB or eSATA)) with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). This system boots in BIOS mode and UEFI mode, and the install process is quite automatic.